# How to install bootstrap-3 on Meteor 0.9?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just installed Meteor 0.9, and I get the following when trying to install bootstrap-3 in my project:

> Error: conflict: foldor:bootstrap-3 can't be satisfied

This error is thrown in response the following command [recommended on atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/foldor/bootstrap-3):

```
meteor add foldor:bootstrap-3
```

I created a new Meteor 0.9 project to try to get this working in isolation, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 year later, Bootstrap is officially released as a Meteor package.

See 3.3.4 changelog http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/03/16/bootstrap-3-3-4-released/

> [*Bootstrap is now also available as a Meteor package in the Atmosphere package index*](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap)

Answer (score 14):

Someone forked the repo and published another version, since the original maintainer was taking a while to answer a pull request to update the package. The following seems to work fine.

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Comment: I get : `mizzao:bootstrap-3: no such package`

Comment: As a resource, be sure to check [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/), which is a meteor package source.

Comment: If the `mizzao` package doesn't work for you, see my answer below about the new officially supported package

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the issue I raised in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2443.

I forked the package and published a version that would not raise this error. See the other answer for how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the popular `mizzao:bootstrap-3` lacks certain features, such as the duplicate icon. I recommend installing the officially supported package instead:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

Of course, I have much gratitude for the `mizzao` package that has been keeping us going. Just wanted to make sure this option is known. See their [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for details